# Apache Windows httpd.conf AccessFileName problem

Tags: apache, apache2, apache-commons, apache-config

I am using Apache 2.2.17 for Windows. To set up `.htaccess` file, when I was going through `httpd.conf` file, I was not able to find the word called `“AccessFileName”`. I believe there should be a line like this: `AccessFileName .htaccess`. How can I solve this?

[Here](http://paste.pocoo.org/show/374539/) is the `httpd.conf` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by changing `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All` inside `<Directory>`

Answer (score 2):

The `AccessFileName .htaccess` is default.  If it is not present, that is what it's using.  If you would to like use a different filename, you can add the line in and replace `.htaccess` accordingly.

Comment: i want to set directory to htaccess file.. where should i include access file name in the configuration file?? I have posted my file..

Answer (score 1):

As you can read [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#accessfilename)

It says:

> While processing a request the server
>   looks for the first existing 
>   configuration file from this list of
>   names in every directory of the path
>   to the document, if distributed
>   configuration files are enabled for
>   that directory. For example:
>
> AccessFileName .acl
>
> before returning the document
>   /usr/local/web/index.html, the server
>   will read /.acl, /usr/.acl,
>   /usr/local/.acl and
>   /usr/local/web/.acl for directives,
>   unless they have been disabled with
>
> <Directory> AllowOverride None
>   </Directory>